# Unshow variable in Debug Java Eclipse when add jar file

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, debugging

I use jxl-2.6.9.jar to read excel in java by eclipse. But when I debug:

1)it shows "source not found". And when i use any *.jar file it still show "source not found" and doesn't show any variables. It debug too long to see variables.

2)It just show a lot of line of "Launcher, Event Dispath ...", doesn't show line by line on code as normal dubug when don't use jar file.

3)I search on google some ways as: "Edit source lookup path" but it doesn't work.

4)Console: No thing.

5) Project run good but not debug.

Comment: what does the console-view sáy. is the application still running or terminated? my suggestion is that you either have not activated line numbers in your compiler settings (either global eclipse settings, or project specific settings) or you never reach your breakpoint.

Comment: can you take a look at your eclipse preferences "menu: window -> prferences", navigate to Java/Compiler and let me know what the status of te "Add line number attributes to generated class file (used by the debugger)" checkbox is.

Comment: to your point 3. you need the exact source code of the library you want to debug if you want this to work. and your library needs to have line numbers compiled into it.

Comment: "add line number attributes ..." is cheked.

Comment: can you please edit your question and post the stacktrace? make sure that you don't have project specific compiler settings. right click on project->properties --> similar to the general preferences. any chance it's a maven project?

Comment: my project is very simple, just read excel. Other projects dont use jar file is normal debug.

Answer (score 1):

While debugging try STEP OVER(F6) instead of STEP INTO(F5) maybe the 'source not found ' errors which you are getting were in relation to external libraries which you do not need to debug.
Thanks! and if the solution doesn't work,please attach a screenshot of your problem it will be more easy to understand the exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't have a problem switching to jxl-2.6.12 you can download the jar and the sources [here at maven central](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.sourceforge.jexcelapi%22)

when eclipse tells you "source not found" point it to the source file.

i would strongly recommend using maven in the future, even for small projects. with maven you can automatically download source and documentation for your external libraries.

Comment: I download file and put it into project but it is still the same error.

Comment: have you changed your classpath, i mean removed the other version and replaced it with the newer one?

Comment: did you download the source file too from the maven link?

Comment: Yes, i removed old version.

Comment: set a breakpoint in your code where you call a jxl method or constructor. when in debugger then say step into. then select the sources.jar file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134293/discussion-between-alex-m-and-dang-hoang).

Comment: eclipse doesn't show any line of code when I debug. it just show "Source not found"